# iScroll scrollToElement not working with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, iscroll

I have something similar to this iScroll example: http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/

Except that I'm using jQuery mobile (i.e., the header, footer, and content are set using jQuery Mobile). Everything is running smoothly except for scrollToElement.

Is there any way to get scrollToElement working when using jQuery Mobile and iScroll?

Here's the iScroll script I currently have:

```
var myScroll;
function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
 }
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200);}, false);
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention what I'm trying to achieve. In the iScroll example mentioned above, I'm trying to scroll to a specific row. The only problem is that jQuery Mobile prevents scrollToElement from working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I have found is to capture the elements position and then use `scrollToPage()`:

```javascript
var w = $("#showselectedauthors").offset().top;
// ...
$.storeScroller.scrollToPage(0, w);
```

Of course for this to work you have to capture the position when the element is visible or the offset will be meaningless. You can do this when the page is built but before the scroller is initialized.

In my case the element is visible and I capture `w` at that time. I then refresh some content and refresh the scroller. After I do that I want to make sure the element is still visible.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you're using a timeout

```
         setTimeout(function () {
            myScroll.scrollToElement(".elementClass", "0s");
            myScroll.refresh();
        }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Case anyone needs to scroll to a jQuery Object here's my code .
Make sure you're calling this method inside a setTimeout and your "iscroll" object is defined .

```
function scrollToElement($element) {
    if ($element.size() > 1) {
        throw new Error("Cannot be a node!");
    };
    var offset = $element.offset().top;
    var to = -(offset - iscroll.y);
    to = (iscroll.maxScrollY > to) ? iscroll.maxScrollY : to;
    iscroll.scrollTo(0, to);
}
```